# Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax.Module to Template Haskell data structure

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I've got a Module ([`Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax.Module`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Module)) and want to turn it into a template haskell data structure. How can I go about it? My first confusion is that the `Module` type from [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Module) doesn't look like a representation of a haskell module (it only has a `PkgName` and a `ModName`). So what's equivalent to `Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax.Module` in template haskell? Is there a way to convert between the two?

Comment: "So what's equivalent to Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax.Module in template haskell?" There is none, it simply doesn't support it. You cannot splice an entire module (at least yet).

Comment: Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I would assume that it is a majour technical challenge, and there hasn't been much demand for it. I don't know how it would even work - you can't have a module inside a module.

Comment: That makes sense. If you put your first comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax.Module` in Template Haskell, it simply doesn't support it. You cannot splice an entire module (at least yet).